# calculating the duration and the order of non-continuous events in R

Tags: r, events, rank, duration

My dataset consists of a series of behaviours observed in videos. For each behaviour, I have recorded when it starts and when it ends.

```
datain <-data.frame(
            A=c("1/5+11/18","0/5","7/10"),
            B=c("6/10+19/25","11/15","11/20"),
            C=c("26/30","6/10","0/6"))
```

I would like to get the duration of each behaviour as well as the order of the behaviours for each observation, like in this desired output

```
dataout <-data.frame(
            A=c("1/5+11/18","0/5","7/10"),
            B=c("6/10+19/25","11/15","11/20"),
            C=c("26/30","6/10","0/6"),
            A.sum=c(11,5,3),
            B.sum=c(10,4,9),
            C.sum=c(4,4,6),
myorder=c("A/B/A/B/C","A/C/B","C/A/B"))
```

I am experimenting with the following lines to identify which columns have the + and to extract the rows with the interrupted behaviours (but I still have to calculate the duration of each behaviour), but I guess there could be more efficient solution than the one I am currently attempting.

```
d.1 <- lapply(datain, function(x) str_which(x,"\\+"))
d.2 <- which(lapply(d.1,length)>0)
coltosum <- match(names(d.2),colnames(datain))

mylist <- lapply(datain[coltosum],function(x) strsplit(x,"\\+"))
```

As always, I would greatly appreciate any suggestion.

Please note that I have edited this question after some days to include in the desired output the order of the behaviours.

Update: I have been able to figure out how to get the sequence of the behaviours. I bet there are more elegant and concise ways to get this result. Below the code

```
#removing empty columns
empty_columns <- sapply(datain, function(x) all(is.na(x) | x == ""))
datain<- datain[, !empty_columns]

#loop 1#
#this loop is for taking the occurrence of BH
mylist <- list()

for (i in seq(1,nrow(datain))){
mylist <- apply(datain,1,str_extract_all,pattern="\\d+")
myindx <- sapply(mylist, length)
myres <- c(do.call(cbind,lapply(mylist, `length<-`,max(myindx))))
names(myres) <- rep(colnames(datain),nrow(datain))
mydf <- ldply(myres,data.frame)
colnames(mydf) <- c("BH","values")
}

#loop 2#
#this loop is for counting the number of elements in a nested list
mydf.1 <- list()
myres.2 <- list()

for (i in seq(1,nrow(datain))){
mydf.1 <- length(unlist(mylist[i]))
myres.2[i] <- mydf.1
}

#this is for placing the row values
names(myres.2) <- rownames(datain)
myres.3 <- as.numeric(myres.2)

mydf$myrow <- c(rep(rownames(datain),myres.3))

#I can order by row and by values
mydf <- mydf[order(as.numeric(mydf$myrow),as.numeric(mydf$values)),]

#I have to pick up the right values
#I have to generate as many sequences as many elements for each row.
myseq <- sequence(myres.3)
mydf <- cbind(mydf,myseq)

myseq.2 <- seq(1,nrow(mydf),by=2)

#selecting the df according to the uneven row
mydf.1 <- mydf[myseq.2,]
myorder <-split(mydf.1,mydf.1$myrow) 

#loop 3

myres.3 <- list()
for (i in seq(1,nrow(datain))){
myres.3 <- lapply(myorder,"[",i=1)
}

myorder.def <- data.frame(cbind(lapply(myres.3,paste0,collapse="/")))
colnames(myorder.def) <- "BH"

#last step, apply str_extract_all for each row
myorder.def$BH <- str_replace_all(myorder.def$BH,"c","")
myorder.def$BH <- str_replace_all(myorder.def$BH,"\\(","")
myorder.def$BH <- str_replace_all(myorder.def$BH,"\\)","")
myorder.def$BH <- str_replace_all(myorder.def$BH,"\"","")
myorder.def$BH <- str_replace_all(myorder.def$BH,", ","/")

data.out <- cbind(datain,myorder.def)
data.out
```

Stef

Answer (score 3):

An option in `base R` would be to loop over the columns (`lapply`) of the dataset, then replace the digits (`\\d+`) followed by `/` and digits to denominator - numerator by capturing those digits and switching the backreferences (`\\2-\\1`), and `eval(parse` the string

```
datain[paste0(names(datain), ".sum")] <- lapply(datain, function(y) 
   sapply(gsub("(\\d+)/(\\d+)", "(\\2-\\1)", y), 
     function(x) eval(parse(text = x))))
```

-checking with OP's output

```
> datain
              A         B    C A.sum B.sum C.sum
1 3/4+6/8+11/16 0/5+15/20  0/5     8    10     5
2           0/5      5/10 3/10     5     5     7
> dataout
              A        B    C A.sum B.sum C.sum
1 3/4+6/8+11/16 0/5+10/5  0/5     8    10     5
2           0/5     5/10 3/10     5     5     7
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`, group by rows, loop `across` all the columns, read the string into a data.frame with `read.table`, subtract the columns, get the `sum` and return as new columns by modifying the `.names`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
datain %>% 
  rowwise %>%
   mutate(across(everything(), ~ sum(with(read.table(text = 
   str_replace_all(.x,  fixed("+"), "\n"), sep = "/",
    header = FALSE), V2 - V1)), .names = "{.col}.sum")) %>% 
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 6
  A             B         C     A.sum B.sum C.sum
  <chr>         <chr>     <chr> <int> <int> <int>
1 3/4+6/8+11/16 0/5+15/20 0/5       8    10     5
2 0/5           5/10      3/10      5     5     7
```

Comment: actually with solution number 1 I got: Error: unexpected input in "datain[paste0(names(datain), ".sum")] <- lapply(datain, \". Solution number 2 is excellent though! Thank you very much @akrun!

Comment: @stefano That is just because you have an older `R version`, You can change it to `function(x)` and `function(y)` as lambda.

Answer (score 2):

Another base R approach might be the following. First split by `+`, then split again by `/`, taking the `sum` of `diff`erences in the resulting values.

```
datain[paste0(names(datain), ".sum")] <-
  lapply(datain, function(x) {
    sapply(strsplit(x, "[+]"), function(y) { 
      sum(sapply(strsplit(y, "[/]"), function(z) { 
        diff(as.numeric(z)) }
      ))
    })
  })
datain
```

**Output**

```
              A         B    C A.sum B.sum C.sum
1 3/4+6/8+11/16 0/5+15/20  0/5     8    10     5
2           0/5      5/10 3/10     5     5     7
```

Answer (score 1):

Update:

Slightly improved:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
datain %>%
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
  separate_rows(value, sep = "\\+|\\/", convert = TRUE) %>% 
  group_by(group = rleid(name)) %>% 
  mutate(value = value - lag(value, default = value[1])) %>% 
  slice(which(row_number() %% 2 == 0)) %>% 
  mutate(value = sum(value),
         name = paste0(name, ".sum")) %>%
  slice(1) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-group) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value) %>%
  select(-id) %>% 
  cbind(datain)
```

This row
`separate_rows(value, sep = "\\+|\\/", convert = TRUE) %>%`

is same as

```
 separate_rows(value, sep = "\\+") %>% 
 separate_rows(value, sep = "\\/") %>% 
 type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%
```

The very very long way until finish: :-)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
datain %>%
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
  separate_rows(value, sep = "\\+") %>% 
  separate_rows(value, sep = "\\/") %>% 
  group_by(group =as.integer(gl(n(),2,n()))) %>% 
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(x = value - lag(value, default = value[1])) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(group = rleid(name)) %>% 
  mutate(x = sum(x)) %>% 
  mutate(labels = paste0(name, ".sum")) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-c(name, group, value)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = labels,
              values_from = x,
              values_fn = list) %>% 
  unnest(cols = c(A.sum, B.sum, C.sum)) %>% 
  cbind(datain)
```

```
  A.sum B.sum C.sum             A         B    C
1     8    10     5 3/4+6/8+11/16 0/5+15/20  0/5
2     5     5     7           0/5      5/10 3/10
```